# Ordering array in twig after sorting it

Tags: twig

Let's say I'm having array in twig

```
{% set temp = [
  {"name": 'Tom', 'lname': 'Marko'},
  {"name": 'Nick', 'lname': 'Montana'},
  {"name": 'Tina', 'lname': 'Marko'},
  {"name": 'Mike', 'lname': 'Miles'}
] %}
```

Is it possible to first sort it by `lname` and then order by `name` right in template and make it look like

```
{% set temp = [
  {"name": 'Tina', 'lname': 'Marko'},
  {"name": 'Tom', 'lname': 'Marko'},
  {"name": 'Mike', 'lname': 'Miles'},
  {"name": 'Nick', 'lname': 'Montana'}
] %}
```

or I have to sort and order it before passing to template or create extension to make it possible in template?

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi you read question? You checked doc? Then it's not answering my question, unless you see more... It's letting to sort and I want to sort by `lname` and order by `name`

Comment: Isn't sorting just the same as ordering?

Comment: Please find answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html

You would need:

```
{% set temp = [
  {"name": 'Tom', 'lname': 'Marko'},
  {"name": 'Nick', 'lname': 'Montana'},
  {"name": 'Tina', 'lname': 'Marko'},
  {"name": 'Mike', 'lname': 'Miles'}
]%}

{% for tmp in temp|sort((a, b) => (a.name <=> b.name))|sort((a, b) => (a.lname <=> b.lname)) %}
    {{ tmp.name }} {{ tmp.lname }}
{% endfor %}
```

This yeilds:

```
Tina Marko
Tom Marko
Mike Miles
Nick Montana
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/qu3yvj)